# Multiprocessing in Flask

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

I have this code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import thread
from multiprocessing import Process

app = Flask(__name__)

def print_time():
   i = 0
   while 1:
      i += 1

def server():
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return 'Index Page'

    @app.route('/hello/')
    def hello(name=None):
        return render_template('index.html', name=i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target=server).start()
    Process(target=print_time).start()
```

But I get an error that says:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\envs\hvc\dashboard.py", line 15
return 'Index Page'
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I am not using it in debug mode.

Comment: The actual error message is missing.

Comment: And what is the exception?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: So sorry, the error is this...File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\envs\hvc\dashboard.py", line 15
    return 'Index Page'
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Please add the message to your original question.

Comment: Probably mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: Nope, I use sublime.

Comment: `IndentationError` has absolutely nothing to do with multiprocessing. As was suggested, you're probably mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: I reworte the code. Indentation error is gone. My bad.

Comment: In place of while loop, there will be another script which generates data in a loop. This is just for testing purpose to print data on browser

Comment: If you've fixed the original error and you've got a new one, make a new question for it. Don't edit a question such that a previous answer (then valid) can become invalid. Also, accept the valid answer.

Comment: I thank everyone who tried to help me but the problem is server is not starting! Does that mean wrong implementation of the code? or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

The code mixes tabs and spaces.

These two lines:

```
    def index():
        return 'Index Page'
```

Are actually:

```
[tab]def index():
    [tab]return 'Index Page'
```

When tabs are used in Python source code, they are first replaced with spaces until the first column that is a multiple of 8. That makes the above euivalent to:

```
        def index():
        return 'Index Page'
```

So, the `return` line is not indented.

The moral of the story is: do not use tabs. Configure the editor to replace tabs with 4 spaces.